# Share logger in python

Tags: python, logging

I have a project that uses 3rd party packages (which in turn might be using other packages). I want to apply a common `xxxHandler` to all packages logging. Since all packages define `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, this is the solution I have implemented:

```py
handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename='app.log')
for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    logging.getLogger(name).addHandler(handler)
```

This works, but it creates multiple entries per log (probably because of logging propagation). So, I enhanced this a bit by providing a list of `names` that should get the handler:

```py
def add_handler_to_loggers(loggers=None):
    if loggers:
        for name in loggers:
            logging.getLogger(name).addHandler(handler)

add_handler_to_loggers(['requests', 'sleekxmpp']
```

And I am happy with this. However, I am not sure I will be missing any important log from some other package.

**Questions**

1. Is this a good approach for my problem?
2. Is there a better approach?

Thank you!

Comment: It's better to just add one single handler to root, and have the other loggers propagate there. (which by default they do)

Comment: @blues You are right. Instead of working with the root handler, I used `getLogger(__name__)` which did not captured the propagated events, that's why I searched for a solution. Thank you, you may add this as an answer.